# Order of permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm invoking the following:

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissions, requestCode);
```

I request the following permissions:

```
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS
```

Now, my app requires that the user select "All the time" for the location permission. So if the user selects "Only while using this app", Android will show a subsequent screen asking them to select "All the time".

The problem is that the user sees the initial location permission request, followed by the audio request, followed by the "All the time" location request.

It seems no matter what order I make the list "permissions" parameter in the requestPermissions method, I can't make audio be requested first.

Any ideas of how to get this done? Or if Android by default requests them in a fixed order?

Comment: Read the docs: Therefore, it's recommended that your app performs incremental requests for location permissions, asking for foreground location access and then background location access.

Comment: Right, but that doesn't change the fact that I can't reorder the audio and location permissions.

Comment: Every body can.

Comment: Everybody can what?

Answer (score 0):

You need to request course or precise location FIRST, then when one or both of them is granted you can request background permission. You can't request them at the same time.
Or you can just use this library that I have been working on for a while. It is inspired by how google fit is doing it.

https://github.com/warting/permissions-ui

It is also dealing with different android SDK:s, rationales and permanent denied scenarios.

Only ask for background and audio permissions when needed. Not both at the same time just because you might need it later.